# Interface method execution

Tags: java, interface

I have a question when i implement interface.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
   An icon that has the shape of the planet Mars.
*/
public class MarsIcon implements Icon
{
   /**
      Constructs a Mars icon of a given size.
      @param aSize the size of the icon
   */
   public MarsIcon(int aSize)
   {
      size = aSize;
   }

   public int getIconWidth()
   {
      return size;
   }

   public int getIconHeight()
   {
      return size;
   }

   public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
   {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Ellipse2D.Double planet = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y,
            size, size);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.fill(planet);
   }

   private int size;
}

    import javax.swing.*;

public class IconTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, 
            "Hello, Car!",
            "Message",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            new MarsIcon(100));
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

In the IconTester, i only create a MarsIcon(100). I have not call the method. But it seems that the paintIcon(;;;) is executed. 
How come? Are the methods called automatically?

Comment: `paintIcon` gets called when you try to display the icon. Since you are displaying a message dialog with that icon, it will be called.

Comment: If you would have debugged and checked the call stack, you would have seen who is calling `paintIcon`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't call the `paintIcon` method directly, this happens by the display manager when your component is part of the visible UI.

And here it is, because you added it to a `JOptionPane`.